# My thingsboard service does not start or can't find one after installing the rpm package in amazon ami

Tags: thingsboard

My thingsboard service does not start or can't find one after installing the rpm package in amazon ami. There is no .sh file in find only a jar and yaml file.

Comment: What AMI are you using? Thingsboard AMI is based on Ubuntu 16.04 and you can't install rpm there.

Answer (score -1):

The Thingsboard RPM package you are using is verified on CentOS 7. The issue is that Amazon Linux AMI is not compatible with CentOS 7. See [this AWS forum thread](https://www.google.com/url?q=https%3A%2F%2Fforums.aws.amazon.com%2Fthread.jspa%3FthreadID%3D146805&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNEFbOgnn1_MHf7MnhtqD_aZ1YcXBg) for more details.
Maybe we will support AWS Linux in future releases, but for now, I suggest to use officially supported Linux versions.

You can get started with Thingsboard using our [free live demo server](https://www.google.com/url?q=https%3A%2F%2Fdemo.thingsboard.io%2Fsignup&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNFBzVq-41Q1ALd2QW2f3rAg74205w) or by using [pre-defined AMIs](https://www.google.com/url?q=https%3A%2F%2Fthingsboard.io%2Fdocs%2Fuser-guide%2Finstall%2Faws%2F&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNEFXUwOjSrBdgtXPLlupwzshRYt6Q) that are available for all regions.

Thanks,
Andrew